# Conservative vectorfield with norms

Tags: geometry, analysis, mathematical-physics

We let $F,G :\mathbb R^3\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ be vector fields given by:
$$F(x,y,z)=(x^2,0,y^2)$$
$$G(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{1}{1+\|(x,y,z)\|^2}x,\frac{1}{1+\|(x,y,z)\|^2}y,\frac{1}{1+\|(x,y,z)\|^2}z \right)$$
and we let $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R^3$ be two paths from $(0, 0, 0)$ to $(1, 1, 1)$ defined as:
$$\gamma_1(t)=(t,t^2,t^3), \gamma_2(t)=\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right), 1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi t}{2}\right),t\right)$$

Then I have to prove that $F$ is not a conservative vector field and find out if there exist an open subset $O \subset \mathbb R^3$ such that the restriction $F : O \to\mathbb R^3$
is conservative? And I have to find out whether $G$ is conservative or not?
I think I can prove that F is not a conservative vector field by that:
$\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial y} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial }{\partial z}(0)=\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(y^2 ) \Leftrightarrow 0\neq 2y$ therefore we have proof that the curl is not zero, so $F$ is path-dependent and thereby not conservative. But how do I find whether if there exists these interval $O$ and how do I deal with differentiating the norms in $G$ so I can show whether $G$ is conservative or not? Hope anyone can help me?

Comment: Well, is $2y=0$ an open set?

Comment: I'm confused what they mean by open set? But this is only possible for $y=0$ and not for an open set?

Comment: I voted to reject an edit by bittahProfessional although _some_ of what it did was good, but bittahProfessional clearly did not understand the term "restriction of a function", and possibly too much was changed.

Comment: Exactly, now you get it. Lastly for the other field, try integrating directly

Comment: @bittahProfessional if you see this comment: What was posted included this: "there exist an open subset $O\subset R^3$ such that the restriction $F:O\to R^3$ is conservative". That is a correct use of the term restriction. The mapping $F:O\to R^3$ is a restriction. A statement about it's being conservative is not a restriction. "Restriction of a function" is a standard term; a restriction of a function is a certain kind of (other) function.

Comment: For the second one, the vector field is $ \frac{1}{1 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2}(x, y, z)$ and you can show that the curl is $(0, 0, 0)$

Comment: Or if you are familiar with spherical coordinates, you can write it as $\vec G = \frac{r ~\hat r}{1+r^2}$